# How to update deletedAt timestamp in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to update deletedAt field but it is not including it in the update query. I don't want to use `user.destroy()`.

Here is my code

**Method 1:**

```
const user = await User.findByPk(2, {
  paranoid: false
});
user.deletedAt = moment().toDate();
user.status    = UserStatus.INACTIVE;
await user.save({
  logging: true
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
await user.update({
  deletedAt: moment().toDate(),
  status: UserStatus.INACTIVE
}, {
  logging: true,
});
```

**Result Query:**

```
Executing (default): UPDATE `users` SET `status`='inactive',`updatedAt`='2019-12-24 11:54:12' WHERE `id` = 2
```

Comment: Method 2 update query is not logged, can you share the result query for method 2??

Comment: query is same for both. Sequelize is ignoring deletedAt key

Comment: could you please tell us why don't you want to use destroy ?